# Product image upload button has changed to 'couldn't load plugin'

Tags: magento-1.9, error, image-upload

On the images section of the product upload, the button that usually says upload has changed to 'couldn't load plugin'.

Any idea why this is happening or how I can fix it?

Comment: Update flash player should resolve your issue.

Comment: @AmanAlam Updating flash didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue when I had extended and created my own theme for the admin area.

These buttons use FLASH.

So if your browser does not support flash - then they will not appear.

Ensure that the

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media
```

folder exists and that there are 2 files within it.

```
editor.phtml
uploader.phtml
```

Ensure that the

```
skin/adminhtml/default/default/media
```

folder exists and that there are 3 files within it.

```
flex.swf
uploader.swf
uploaderSingle.swf
```

If you have created your own theme (ie Theme: "mytheme" and Package "mypackage") then ensure the above applies for:

```
app/design/adminhtml/mytheme/mypackage/template/media
skin/adminhtml/mytheme/mypackage/media
```

I hope this helps.